# Is it possible to project entities with 1-to-M children resulting in a single SQL query?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am aware that by projecting (or "shaping") the result in a LINQ-to-SQL or LINQ-to-Entities query, one can nudge the resulting SQL query to something more performant than without.

Two excellent articles on this can be found here [by Eugene Prystupa](https://eprystupa.wordpress.com/2009/11/26/linq-to-sql-tricks-building-efficient-queries-that-include-reference-data-or-child-entities/), and here [by Rick Strahl](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Oct/12/LINQ-to-SQL-Lazy-Loading-and-Prefetching).

Note that in the examples given in these articles, the projections only include children with 1-to-1 relationships to the starting point. E.g., `Order.Customer`, `Order.Date`, etc. When I include entities with 1-to-M relationships, e.g. `Order.OrderItems`, I end up with multiple SQL queries being generated: one on table `Order` and at least `n` queries on table `OrderItem`, where `n` is the number of `Orders` returned from the first query. (I say "at least", because if `OrderItem` also has child entities, these will get their own SQL select queries.)

Example code that results in a single SQL query:

```
Orders.Select(o => new {
    o.Id,
    o.Customer.FirstName,
    o.EmployeeName
}).Take(3)
```

Example code that results in (at least) `n` SQL queries:

```
Orders.Select(o => new {
    o.Id,
    o.Customer.FirstName,
    o.EmployeeName,
    o.OrderItems
}).Take(3)
```

Is it so that you always end up with multiple SQL queries being generated when shaping data with children in a 1-to-M relationship? Or can the LINQ query be rewritten so the result is a single (more performant) SQL query?

(Note that I'm currently using LINQ-to-SQL, but I'd like to know for LINQ-to-Entities as well.)